# I am building a off grid house in Ghana and would like to use an American 200 amp breaker box and plugs

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I am building a off grid house in Ghana and would like to use an American 200 amp breaker box and plugs. Are the solar inverters different? or can I wire it to work?

Comment: You can't use AC breakers for the same DC voltage. They have to be derated a lot. Also, U.S. breaker boxes are meant for split-phase which leads to an arrangement of breakers no too useful for a non-splitphase application.

Comment: Thank You, So can you tell me the best way to wire my house for American power? Should I buy a inverter here in America?

Comment: What kind of electrical code do they adhere to in Ghana? (Realizing that it may be "little to none"...)

Comment: I believe it is little to none it is in small village in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: If you use a inverter that provides power you could use a us type panel but most systems are not large enough to justify a 200 amp panel. A 200 amp panel could Handel 100kva inverter capacity and that is huge. Most of the systems I have installed are between 5-10kva I have installed smaller and larger but not many.

Comment: Thanks! So if I get  a 5000 watt inverter I could just use a 100 amp breaker box?

Comment: I would be buying the solar stuff in Ghana I'm not sure if the European inverter is different from the ones in the US.

Comment: Do think that North American electrical stuff is odd one to rest of world.  If only for your house completely off grid, can buy everything north american, but if connected to grid, stuff gets more complicated.  Mix and matching probably a bad idea even for just the house.

Comment: What's your motivation for wanting to use US-style split phase 240V 60Hz, instead of the European-style single-phase 230V 50Hz that the country's grid uses?  Neither system is particularly better than the other, but you'll have a lot easier time getting parts locally for the Euro style system than for the US style system.

Comment: I will be off grid and I would like to Use my American Appliances and electronic devices.

Comment: What appliances and electronic devices specifically?  I ask because while what you're proposing isn't impossible, it's almost certainly going to be more expensive and have more drawbacks than other solutions.  It also locks you into always having to import electronics from the US, whenever you (or a future owner of this house; don't forget resale value) upgrade or replace anything, rather than being able to pick something up locally.

Comment: Very good point Thanks! The main thing is the washer and dryer I hate the ones I see in Ghana. Can I convert my dryer to run on there power?

Comment: @KeithHammond, those are actually two of the hardest things to convert, but you can certainly find US-style laundry appliances designed to run on the 230V 50Hz power Ghana uses.  Here's some examples:  https://www.world-import.com/220-240-Volt-50-Hertz-washer-dryer.htm

Comment: I've seen expats go to great lengths to take a little piece of home with them.  Usually it's ketchup or high end stereo equipment.  But recreating an American electrical system in a foreign country just because you prefer a top loading washer is in a whole new league.   Take NateS' advice and take mine too: Embrace the change!  Whatever is driving this move, you can't succeed with the mentality of transplanting America wherever you go.

Comment: Well I'm not an expat, I am going off grid and its not just washer I really like  a lot of My American stuff.

Comment: I've summarized my comments into an expanded answer.  Hopefully that will answer your questions.

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer.  Ghana has electrical standards including for solar power, and they are available on line.  But if you will be off grid they probably don't apply to you.  In which case your question, "Are the solar inverters different" has no answer.  Which solar inverters?  Is it possible to purchase an inverter in Ghana that is compatible with your American distribution panel and appliances?  Almost certainly.  Is it possible to purchase one that is inherently incompatible?  Almost certainly.  As you say, "no one was able to answer my question".  We could use some help.

Comment: Also, you want to be "off grid" but you like your American Stuff.  That's ok but it's hard to understand the motivations and constraints of your question when you put it that way.  Which is why you need to spell them out.  Usually when someone says "I'm going off grid" it is almost literally to escape from their American accoutrements.  I'm not judging your motivations, but if you don't spell out your question in detail and also don't tell us what is driving your decisions, it's REALLY hard to help.

Comment: @KeithHammond Living in another country is the definition of an expatriate. :-)

Comment: I know the definition and your not an expatriate when you return to your birth country,

Answer (score 3):

### Two Systems of Electricity

Throughout the world, there are basically two different systems of electricity that (almost) every country uses one of.  Both are safe, and neither is particularly better than the other, but they are different, and not directly compatible.

1. 120/240V 60Hz

This system is used primarily in North America, and is often referred to as US style power or split-phase power.  120V is used for small things, and heavy loads use 240V.

2. 230V 50Hz

This system is used in most of the rest of the world besides North America.  It's sometimes referred to as European style power, as that is where it originated.  Note that while it's 230V nominal, some locations actually use 220V or 240V, which is within acceptable tolerance of 230V.

Since this system is used so widely, the availability of equipment is actually huge -- if you don't like the style of something local, there's probably another country with the same power system that has what you want.  So, for example, while you might not like some of the options local to Ghana, you can always import from the UK, Australia, Germany, China, France, etc., and they will all be compatible with your local power system.

### Build to Local Standards

As I understand it, you're planning to build an off-grid house in a location where the local regulations are lax enough to allow for either system to legally be used.  Since most of the devices you're hoping to power are expecting 120/240V 60Hz power, you're thinking of building that type of system, even though 230V 50Hz is the official standard of the country.  I would strongly advise against this, for many reasons:

- All electronics and electrical building materials used in this house must be imported from North America.  While this might not seem like much extra work when you're building the place, it will be a big pain every time something breaks and needs to be replaced.  This is especially true if the dead item is the inverter, since you'll be without power until you can source a new one.
- Local electricians will not be familiar with, or qualified to work on, a 120V system.  As such, you will have to DIY almost all electrical work, and will have trouble getting good help.  An electrician trained only in a 230V system could easily make dangerous mistakes on a 120/240V system.
- When you eventually sell the place (which will happen someday, as houses almost always outlive their owners), the next person will not be able to plug in their electronics, and will not know how to work on the system.  As such, they will almost certainly want to rip it all out and replace it with the standard system used in the country -- and they'll deduct the price of doing that from the price they're willing to pay for the place.
- When guests come over, they will not be able to plug in their cell phone chargers or other electronics.
- Local regulations may change.  While at the moment, the government in question isn't strictly enforcing that all buildings in the country use the country's official power standard, can you guarantee this will still be true in 30 years?  It's not impossible that the government would make you change it later, at your own expense.

As such, I highly recommend you build a 230V 50Hz system as the primary power system for this house.  In order to use the devices you like, I recommend you evaluate them on a case-by-case basis, and replace them with a 230V version if there's a good one available, or get a converter for only that device.

### Powering Electronics from the Other System

It's very often possible to power devices that were designed for one system on the other one, but how easy that is depends on the device in question.  Broadly, there are three categories:

1. Universal Input Devices

These devices don't care which system they're supplied from, and will happily work on either.  Usually all you need to do is change the cord, or use a passive plug adapter.  They can be identified by their label, which will say something like 100-250V, 50-60Hz.

Most modern DC electronics these days are designed to be universal input.  This includes most computers, cell phone chargers, TVs, etc.  Check your labels; you might be surprised to find how many devices you can use with no conversion.

2. Things that care about voltage, but not frequency.

Things like light bulbs and toasters do need the voltage to be correct, but they do not care at all about frequency.  As such, they can be powered with a transformer of appropriate size (a 240->120V step down transformer in your case).  Again, check the label -- it'll either say 50/60 Hz or it won't mention frequency at all.

3. Things that care about frequency.

These will almost all be electric motors (or things that have them inside, such as AC compressors, and your washer and dryer).  Most low-cost AC electric motors are synchronous with the grid frequency, and will run 20% faster on 60Hz than on 50Hz -- which will likely burn them out.  Frequency isn't nearly so easy to change as voltage, so for these categories of appliances, I recommend replacing them with a local version wherever possible.  If you absolutely must use one of these, then you need a frequency converter, which will be expensive.  On these, the label will specify voltage and frequency exactly.

Note that some motors are not synchronous to the AC frequency.  In that case, they'll be in one of the two above categories.  In particular, newer HVAC units are often coming with 'inverter' compressors, which cost more but allow for better efficiency, and are usually universal input.

Answer (score 1):

North American gear is nice stuff that does not require hard-wiring nearly the way DIN rail breakers do... but there are limitations on using it.

**You cannot use DC power** in a North American style panel box, ***unless** the panel and breakers are listed for DC voltage* ... **which basically means Square D "QO"**.   There are some industrial-line breakers which bolt-on, which may be rated for DC.  Further, most random hardware store "QO" breakers are only rated for 48 volts DC - if you need up to 120V DC you will need to talk to a Square D dealer about special ordering those.

On the AC side, I suppose you could go 120V and NEMA plugs to discourage theft of your equipment... but normally, I'd expect you to want to use indigenous voltage, you know, so you can plug in locally sourced appliances. That would be 230V. **Not every North American panel is rated for 230 volts AC**.  You will need to select panels and breakers which are.  The better stuff - CH, QO are likely to be so.

You can't just use USA 240V breakers, because USA power is 240V *center grounded* or 120V to ground/neutral.  Like

```
 +120V ... Neutral ... -120V
```

except it's AC power so this reverses polarity all the time.   As such, there is 240V *between two points* in an American panel, but it's only insulated for 120V to ground.  That's a big deal.  You need to select the better North American panels which are, in fact, rated for 240V to ground.

Lots of fine print to read in your panel search.

If you are doing solar "big" enough to actually be making 230/400V 3-phase "wye", most North American panel lines offer 3-phase versions of their panels. The popular industrial power in the USA is 277V/480V 3-phase "wye", which is about 20% hotter than you're dealing with. Any North American gear made for 277V/480V is perfectly acceptable on your 230/400V.

Answer (score -1):

I can't speak for any laws in Ghana but to make this work, you would need a power source (e. g. solar plus batteries and inverter) producing 120 V AC or 120/240 V AC split/phase, all preferably 60 Hz. No non-North American system will produce this. If your appliances can tolerate 50 Hz, you could get a European 240 system and feed the panel though a large transformer (assuming you can find one rated for 50 Hz).

Also, to run a 200 amp panel, you'll need a very large power source and inverter. For 200 amps 240 volts, you're talking about 48 KW! If you have a 5 KW inverter, you're talking about 42 amps at 120 volts. In that case, I'd just get a small main-leg panel and don't even bother with a main breaker. Just keep in mind that you're not going to me able to run many American appliances on 5000 watts.

I'm assuming that you would never attach this to an electrical grid. That would never work!

Comment: My breakers and panels are labeled 50/60 Hz 120/240 volts and are from a box store. In the US the power is basically a center tapped transformer with the center tap neutral and each of the other two taps 120 to neutral and 240 between taps. The 200A rating of the panel in not a minimum, it is a maximum and you can have less amperage available if you like, just protect your source.  You could use an autotransformer. Try this link for sizing your transformer. https://forums.mikeholt.com/threads/sizing-transformer.37355/  All of this will be compatable with 50/60Hz.